# Template.googleMap.rendered is not a function

Tags: meteor

I am very new to Meteor, trying to make my first project after the To-do list tutorial on the Meteor's website.

I want to put a Google Map on the website and am somewhat following this example - https://github.com/meteor/mobile-packages/tree/master/examples/solomo

However, I have a different project structure and it looks like this:

```
/client
    /googleMap
        googleMap.html
        googleMap.js
    head.html
    body.html
```

There are of course some other files and folders around that, but they are not important for this question.

Now to the respective files:

**googleMap.html**

```
<template name="googleMap">
  <div id="google-map"></div>
</template>
```

**googleMap.js**

```
var GoogleMap = function(container) {
  var lat = 0;
  var lng = 0;
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
    zoom: 17
  };
  this.map = new google.maps.Map(container, mapOptions);
};

Template.googleMap.rendered(function() {
  var map = new GoogleMap(this.firstNode);
});
```

**head.html**

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
</head>
```

**body.html**

```
<body>
  {{> googleMap}}
</body>
```

I expected (and hoped for) the Google Map to appear, but it doesn't and this error is printed to the console: *Template.googleMap.rendered is not a function*

I have tried moving the `googleMap` folder outside the `client` folder thinking that maybe the code needs to be executed on the server, but that leads to an even bigger problem appearing in the server's console: *ReferenceError: Template is not defined*

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Template.googleMap.rendered = function(){}` change the syntax. you can not have a template code outside client. if you move the code out of it, meteor will try to run the code in both the server and client and obviously template is not available in server

Comment: Thank you. Had you put it as an answer ...

Comment: Someone else answered the same. Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should write :

```
Template.googleMap.rendered = function() {
   var map = new GoogleMap(this.firstNode);
}
```